# problem running broadcom 43142 wifi behind cyberoam firewall

Tags: networking, network-manager

My college uses cyberoam firewall.

**The Problem:**

1. Sometimes ,The wifi disconnects and tries to reconnect frequently and hence doesn't let me browse the internet.
2. Other times, the wifi shows up but it isn't running.I have to disconnect and reconnect to wifi again to browse the internet.

The internet speed is too less as compared to those of my friends browsing on windows. On home network, my internet works very well.

I am running ubuntu 16.04 on dell vostro 3446

Network controller: `Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)`

Related syslogs-:

```
  Jul 20 21:37:58 laptop kernel: [ 6194.113226] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: IN
Jul 20 21:37:58 laptop kernel: [ 6194.113231] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: JP
Jul 20 21:37:58 laptop kernel: [ 6194.113234] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Jul 20 21:37:58 laptop kernel: [ 6194.113238] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:37:58 laptop kernel: [ 6194.113241] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:37:58 laptop kernel: [ 6194.113244] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Jul 20 21:37:58 laptop kernel: [ 6194.113247] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=74:a0:2f:d9:6a:b0 reason=0
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030926.4733] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop gnome-session[1657]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161701] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161705] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161707] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161710] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161712] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161714] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161716] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161719] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161720] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161722] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop kernel: [ 6242.161724] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Jul 20 21:38:46 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Jul 20 21:38:47 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Jul 20 21:38:47 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: Failed to initiate AP scan
Jul 20 21:38:48 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030928.5750] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <warn>  [1469030942.1787] device (wlp6s0): link timed out.
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030942.1788] device (wlp6s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [100 120 53]
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030942.1791] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030942.1792] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop whoopsie[846]: [21:39:02] offline
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <warn>  [1469030942.2824] device (wlp6s0): Activation: failed for connection 'SLIET'
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop dbus[808]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030942.2852] device (wlp6s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none') [120 30 0]
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::3e28:4c06:e4b3:ca58 on wlp6s0.
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp6s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3e28:4c06:e4b3:ca58.
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: Interface wlp6s0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030942.3048] dhcp4 (wlp6s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 13790
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030942.3048] dhcp4 (wlp6s0): state changed bound -> done
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: Withdrawing address record for 172.21.4.99 on wlp6s0.
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlp6s0.IPv4 with address 172.21.4.99.
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: Interface wlp6s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030942.3080] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop gnome-session[1657]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop dnsmasq[1340]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop gnome-session[1657]: (deja-dup-monitor:2384): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 2543 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop dbus[808]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp6s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wlp6s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jul 20 21:39:02 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030942.5696] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Jul 20 21:39:07 laptop whoopsie[846]: [21:39:07] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719601] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719645] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 556 at /build/linux-BvkamA/linux-4.4.0/net/wireless/sme.c:850 cfg80211_roamed+0x86/0xa0 [cfg80211]()
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719649] Modules linked in: pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) rfcomm bnep binfmt_misc rtsx_usb_ms memstick btusb btrtl btbcm btintel intel_rapl uvcvideo bluetooth x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp videobuf2_vmalloc coretemp videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 videobuf2_core v4l2_common kvm_intel kvm videodev wl(POE) irqbypass snd_hda_codec_hdmi crct10dif_pclmul dell_laptop dcdbas dell_wmi hid_rmi sparse_keymap crc32_pclmul media dell_smm_hwmon dell_led aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic gf128mul snd_hda_intel glue_helper snd_soc_rt5640 ablk_helper snd_hda_codec snd_soc_rl6231 cfg80211 snd_soc_core snd_hda_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_hwdep snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_rawmidi snd_pcm snd_seq cryptd snd_seq_device input_leds snd_timer joydev snd_soc_sst_acpi serio_raw elan_i2c snd soundcore i2c_designware_platform lpc_ich mei_me mei dell_rbtn dw_dmac i2c_designware_core shpchp dw_dmac_core spi_pxa2xx_platform 8250_dw mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb nouveau i915 mxm_wmi ttm i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper psmouse syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops ahci drm r8169 libahci mii sdhci_acpi wmi sdhci video i2c_hid hid fjes
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719743] CPU: 1 PID: 556 Comm: wl_event_handle Tainted: P        W  OE   4.4.0-28-generic #47-Ubuntu
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719746] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Vostro 3446/0JKRPT, BIOS A01 03/28/2014
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719749]  0000000000000286 0000000034d1df72 ffff8800c3f83dc8 ffffffff813eb1a3
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719753]  0000000000000000 ffffffffc063abd0 ffff8800c3f83e00 ffffffff81081102
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719757]  ffff8800c3bd0000 ffff880034c89240 0000000000000083 ffff88009b86fc80
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719762] Call Trace:
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719770]  [<ffffffff813eb1a3>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719775]  [<ffffffff81081102>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719778]  [<ffffffff8108124a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719796]  [<ffffffffc0617b96>] cfg80211_roamed+0x86/0xa0 [cfg80211]
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719865]  [<ffffffffc08ec955>] wl_notify_roaming_status+0xc5/0x140 [wl]
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719913]  [<ffffffffc08ebfb0>] wl_event_handler+0x60/0x1d0 [wl]
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719961]  [<ffffffffc08ebf50>] ? wl_notify_scan_status+0x320/0x320 [wl]
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719965]  [<ffffffff810a0808>] kthread+0xd8/0xf0
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719969]  [<ffffffff810a0730>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719974]  [<ffffffff81827a4f>] ret_from_fork+0x3f/0x70
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719977]  [<ffffffff810a0730>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1e0/0x1e0
Jul 20 21:39:09 laptop kernel: [ 6264.719980] ---[ end trace 4b2870d11be25115 ]---
Jul 20 21:39:07 laptop whoopsie[846]: [21:39:07] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030958.3579] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disconnected
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043293] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043297] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043299] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043302] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043304] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043305] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043307] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043310] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043312] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043313] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:39:18 laptop kernel: [ 6274.043315] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4252] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4265] policy: auto-activating connection 'SLIET'
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4276] device (wlp6s0): Activation: starting connection 'SLIET' (fa6628f5-74b0-465b-8591-614788bea7be)
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4281] device (wlp6s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4283] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4290] device (wlp6s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4294] device (wlp6s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'SLIET' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4294] Config: added 'ssid' value 'SLIET'
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4295] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4295] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4624] sup-iface[0x1e9d6c0,wlp6s0]: config: set interface ap_scan to 1
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: Trying to associate with 74:a0:2f:d9:6a:b0 (SSID='SLIET' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.4737] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: Associated with 74:a0:2f:d9:6a:b0
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 74:a0:2f:d9:6a:b0 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.5110] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.5111] device (wlp6s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless network 'SLIET'.
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.5114] device (wlp6s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.5120] dhcp4 (wlp6s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030968.5151] dhcp4 (wlp6s0): dhclient started with pid 14073
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=IN
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop kernel: [ 6284.205857] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: IN
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop kernel: [ 6284.205874] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: JP
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop kernel: [ 6284.205879] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop kernel: [ 6284.205884] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop kernel: [ 6284.205887] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop kernel: [ 6284.205891] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop kernel: [ 6284.205894] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:39:28 laptop dhclient[14073]: DHCPREQUEST of 172.21.4.99 on wlp6s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x203fe6d7)
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop dhclient[14073]: DHCPACK of 172.21.4.99 from 172.21.4.1
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3480]   address 172.21.4.99
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3481]   plen 23 (255.255.254.0)
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3481]   gateway 172.21.4.1
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3482]   server identifier 172.21.4.1
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3482]   lease time 1800
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3482]   nameserver '14.139.5.5'
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3482] dhcp4 (wlp6s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp6s0.IPv4 with address 172.21.4.99.
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: New relevant interface wlp6s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: Registering new address record for 172.21.4.99 on wlp6s0.IPv4.
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3508] device (wlp6s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3514] device (wlp6s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop whoopsie[846]: [21:39:29] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3519] device (wlp6s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.3522] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop dhclient[14073]: bound to 172.21.4.99 -- renewal in 736 seconds.
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.4931] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.4932] policy: set 'SLIET' (wlp6s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.4935] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop dnsmasq[1340]: setting upstream servers from DBus
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop dnsmasq[1340]: using nameserver 14.139.5.5#53
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469030969.5021] device (wlp6s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop dbus[808]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop whoopsie[846]: [21:39:29] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/61
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop whoopsie[846]: [21:39:29] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/61
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop whoopsie[846]: [21:39:29] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/61
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop dbus[808]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp6s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [wlp6s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop gnome-session[1657]: (deja-dup-monitor:2384): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 2543 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop whoopsie[846]: [21:39:29] online
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlp6s0.IPv6 with address fe80::3e28:4c06:e4b3:ca58.
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: New relevant interface wlp6s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul 20 21:39:29 laptop avahi-daemon[748]: Registering new address record for fe80::3e28:4c06:e4b3:ca58 on wlp6s0.*.
Jul 20 21:39:56 laptop firefox.desktop[1916]: * Operation too slow. Less than 128 bytes/sec transferred the last 60 seconds
Jul 20 21:39:56 laptop firefox.desktop[1916]: * Closing connection 8
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=74:a0:2f:d9:6a:b0 reason=0
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469031009.3580] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop gnome-session[1657]: Gjs-Message: JS LOG: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop wpa_supplicant[997]: wlp6s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047320] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047324] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047326] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047329] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047331] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047333] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047335] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047338] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047339] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047341] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop kernel: [ 6325.047343] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Jul 20 21:40:09 laptop NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1469031009.4577] device (wlp6s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
```